# Sign file (Client-Server) PKI-CA

Tags: public-key, pki

I have a use case, the IoT system sending a signed file to the data center and I have an internal CA to read the corresponding public key to verify the signature on the signed file.

I am not sure how the flow work functions if I am sending a signed file from the data center to IoT. Does the CA help to sign the files? And I don't want to read the private key out from a [HSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module) to sign the file--isn't that correct?

Can someone please help with how I could send the signed files from the client to server and server to the client?

To make it a bit more complex, I want to sign and encrypt as well. 
My requirement is to store the private key on a HSM (server-side) on [TPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module) (IoT).

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. A CA signs a _certificate_.

Comment: Yes, CA signs CSR and issues the Digital cert. If I want to use PKI (CA) for sending signed files back and forth between client and server, How does it work?
Issuing CA Private key is on HSM.

Comment: The CA stops being involved once the certificates are created. The files are signed by a private key, and then verified by a public key. You trust the public key if it has a certificate signed by the CA that you trust.

Comment: Thank Jack. I agree with you from IoT to the Datacenter use case. But how would I achieve this from the server to IoT? If I generate keypairs on the servers side and send signed cert to the IoT for it to verify but I am not really securing the private key in the secure storage. my requirement is to store the private key in HSM.

Comment: Is the issue how to send the TPM-held key to the certificate authority for signing?

Comment: You can ask an HSM or TPM to generate the secret key inside its hardware and only communicate the public key. Software then turns the public key into a certificate signing request. At that point the TPM can be shipped, as it is no longer involved in the certificate creation (or consumption).

Comment: 1. Generate Key pairs on the HSM.
2. Export public key (csr) from HSM and sign it with CA.
3. send the signed cert to IoT.
4. Now, I have to send the file.
5. How do I read the private key from HSM and sign the file?

Comment: 1.Generate Key pairs on the HSM. 2. Export public key (csr) from HSM and sign it with CA. 3. send the signed cert to IoT. 4. Now, I have to send the file. 


5. How do I read the private key from HSM and sign the file?

Comment: You don't read the private key. A HSM uses the internally stored secret keys to perform cryptographic operations directly. E.g. you could use a private key to sign a file (signature generation includes hashing the file). Or you could use it to unwrap an AES key and use that to decrypt a ciphertext (the wrapped key was generated using the public key wrapping a random data / session key).